# PHP PDO SQLSRV - Can't set LoginTimeout

Tags: php, timeout, sqlsrv

I'm using PHP/PDO/SQLSRV to try to connect to a SQL database to see if the box is up and ready to receive DB commands. I want to limit the timeout to 15 seconds, but I'm unable to make the change to [LoginTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) work:

```
set_time_limit(120);
$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=SERVER_NAME;Database=DB_NAME;LoginTimeout=15";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, 'USER', 'PASS');

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($conn);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

This call takes over 30 seconds to execute. I want it to stop after 15. What am I not setting properly? (PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT doesn't work for SQLSRV)
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT

source [sql srv PDO::setAttribute](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628164%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Good Luck